# Python not executing a shell command that uses variable

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, os.system

I am trying to use a shell command to extract a variable out of it, which I would like to use in the rest of the part of my python program. For example, this code tries to use `subprocess.call` and `os.system`. The former gives me an error while the later doesn't produce anything while both work fine if I do not use a variable in my shell command.

```
import subprocess
import os
# ...

x="05/May/2017"

print 'Date =',x

subprocess.call(['echo Hello World from method 1'], shell=True)
os.system('echo Hello World from method 2')

print "Month from method 1 ="
subprocess.call(['echo $x | cut -f2 -d/'])


print "Month from method 2 ="
m=os.system('echo $x | cut -f2 -d/')
print m
```

Where's the problem and how can I overcome this?

Comment: `x` is a variable of your python script. It is not an environment variable. So, while executing in shell it fails

Comment: How about - `os.system('echo %s | cut -f2 -d/' %x)`?

Comment: There is no reason to an external process at all here. `month = x.split('/')[1]`. Do have a better example in mind for which the correct use of `subprocess.call` could be demonstrated?

Comment: @chepner This is simplified example for a more complicated use of a shell script command (It may have `sed`, `awk` etc and multiple pipelines as well).

Comment: @kuro that works, but `m=os.system('echo %s | cut -f2 -d/' %x)` gives me `0` while I use `print m`.

Comment: Because, `On Unix, the return value is the exit status of the process`

Comment: @kuro Thanks for explaining, but I expected a solution too. 

`m = subprocess.check_output('echo %s | cut -f2 -d/' %x, shell=True);
print m` serves the purpose. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that python variables are not passed to the subprocess (shell command).

Simple solution:

`m=subprocess.getoutput('echo %s | cut -f2 -d/' % (x,))`

`'echo %s | cut -f2 -d/' % (x,)` will first make python replace '%s' with the content of the variable x and then call
`subprocess.getoutput('echo 05/May/2017 | cut -f2 -d/')`

Comment: The approach is correct, but this is still an incorrect use of `call`.

Comment: OK, it works if we add `shell=True` in it. However, I am not being able assign a variable `m` to it, as shown in the original problem.

Comment: I've updated my answer, use `getoutput` instead of `call`.

Comment: @Ramast Thanks. I get `'module' object has no attribute 'getoutput'` error message. However, as mentioned in a comment to @kuro, `subprocess.check_output` works nicely. :)

Comment: are you using python2? in this case u need to use subprocess.check_output(["/bin/sh", "-c", 'echo 05/May/2017 | cut -f2 -d/']) instead

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass an environment variable to a subprocess, you have to explicitly add it to `os.environ`, as below. The other option would be to  create a new environment and pass that to `.call`.

```
import subprocess;
import os;
os.environ['foo'] = "bar";
subprocess.call('echo $foo', shell=True);
```

In the above case, you also need `shell=True`, since otherwise `subprocess.call` will look for an executable literally called `echo $foo`.

Of course we could set the command line parameter manually:

```
foo = "bar";
subprocess.call(['echo', foo]);
```

but then it's not an environment variable.

<sub>As for the actual call you're doing, I hope you're running `cut` as subprocess only for experiment's sake, string processing like that would be better done in the Python script itself.</sub>

Comment: Oops, I missed `shell=True` in my second `subprocess.call` line. Once I put that it removes the error.